# SQL script to select information from the same table on each databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to write a SQL script to get information from Table1 on over 10 databases, how would I go about doing that?
In other words, I have over 10 databases with the exact same table called Table1, how can I write a script without repeating my code?

```
SELECT name, dbo.tDBVersion FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE NAME LIKE 'AAA%'
```

I tried the above, but issue is this popup: "The multi-part identifier dbo.tDBVersion could not be bound "

My desired result would be 2 columns: name and dbversion number next to it.

EDIT: All my databases start with AAA

Answer (score 0):

There is a stored procedure called `sp_MSforeachdb`. This will run the same command in each database - for example:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = ''tDBversion'')  SELECT db_name(), col1, col2 FROM tDBversion'
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/

Comment: I see, that gets me 50% way there, now I would just need to display the name of the databases that were queried in a column next to my result, is there a way to do that?

Comment: updated answer - combine it with using the  db_name() function

Comment: I am trying that, but I am getting 'Invalid object name 'dbo.tDBversion'.  
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT DB_NAME(), Version FROM dbo.tDBVersion'

Comment: that table does not exist in one or more of your databases. you will need to alter the command check if the table exists first - see updated answer

Comment: Just noticed what happened. I executed USE master, and the SP runs this 10 times on the master db only. Once I run USE AAA database i had no errors, but I now have the same DB 10 times rather than 10 different DBs

Comment: it does not run 'on the master db'. The database you are connected to does not make a difference, that stored procedure runs the command on each database on the instance - see me previous comment about checking the table existence

Comment: please update your question to include your full statement if you still have issues

Comment: It's okay, I went ahead and done them manually, I just thought there may be a simpler way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and done this manually, then played about with temp tables and got what I wanted with the below:

```
USE AAA
SELECT  DB_Name() 'Database', Version, CodeVersion INTO #TempTable FROM tDBVersion

USE AAB
INSERT INTO #TempTable 
SELECT  DB_Name() 'Database', Version, CodeVersion FROM tDBVersion

USE AAC
INSERT INTO #TempTable 
SELECT  DB_Name() 'Database', Version, CodeVersion FROM tDBVersion

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
-- ORDER BY "Version" asc
DROP TABLE #TempTable

-- My info sticks in the result pane while the table is dropped so that I don't forget to drop it
```